# Largest palindrome made from product of 3 digit numbers. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def palin(k):
   if(str(k) == str(k)[::-1]):
      return True


p = 0
f = 0

while True:
   for i in range(100,1000):
      for k in range(100,1000):
         f = i*k
         if(palin(f)):
            p = f
   break;

print(p)
```

I already know some other way of solving it but can't understand whats wrong with this code. It gives 580085 as asnwer.

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: the actual answer is  906609

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're assuming the last number produced will be the largest. That's a bad assumption. [The last 10 palindromes found by your loop plotted.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=listplot%5B%5B2460,592295%5D,%5B2461,601106%5D,%5B2462,650056%5D,%5B2463,853358%5D,%5B2464,141141%5D,%5B2465,282282%5D,%5B2466,119911%5D,%5B2467,906609%5D,%5B2468,514415%5D,%5B2469,580085%5D%5D) ([or last 50](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/350e9f65-ca6b-42af-b841-499344ab5309#sidebar=compute). Hopefully that's a permanent link). You can see the size of the palindromes found bounces around. 906609 was the *3rd* last palindrome found.

Instead of unconditionally reassigning, make sure the number is larger first:

```
for i in range(100,1000):
   for k in range(100,1000):
      f = i*k
      if(palin(f) and f > p): # Here
         p = f
```

---

A couple side notes

`palin` would be better written as just:

```
def palin(k):
   return (str(k) == str(k)[::-1])
```

Explicitly returning `True`, and relying on the automatic `None` return looks messy.

And the whole `while true`...`break` part is unnecessary. You want to loop forever, but break on the first loop?

Just write:

```
def palin(k):
   return (str(k) == str(k)[::-1])

p = 0
f = 0

for i in range(100,1000):
   for k in range(100,1000):
      f = i*k
      if(palin(f) and f > p):
         p = f

print(p)
```

Comment: One thing that I don't understand is why did it stopped at 580085, there are many palindromes both before and after it.

Comment: @SarthakJha It didn't stop at that number. If you want to see what's going on, add *all* the palindromes you find to a list, then look at the list. Your code shows 580085 because that's that last palindrome found. `i*k` won't always produce larger numbers with each iteration since `k` goes back down to 100 after each iteration of `i`. The size of the numbers ramps up and down.